# Usar un componente de sdk 28 o posterior en SDK 27

Tags: android, material-design, sdk, androidx

Por cuestiones de unas librerías que debo usar por obligación en una app, se tuvo que hacer un downgrade desde SDK 29 a SDK 27. Todo bien, la app funciona bien, el problema es con estilos.

Se tuvo que retirar el com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout que requiere al menos el SDK 28 y sustituir con inputs ordinarios.

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/#outlined-text-field)

¿Hay manera de implementar esos componentes en el SDK 27 o alguien conoce alguna alternativa de algún componente? Quiero evitarme hacer mi propio componente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Realizar downgrade no creo que sea recomendable, que library deseas usar, porque no mejor usar un target a SDK 28 y buscar otras opciones para las Library?

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente no entiendo por qué la biblioteca que usas no tendría compatibilidad con la Api 28 o superiores, el problema es que en este momento la tienda de Google ya no admite aplicaciones con un **targetSdkVersion** menor a 28, es decir que una vez que termines de desarrollar tu app no podrás subirla por este motivo.

Podrías revisar este documento para tener un mayor entendimiento sobre el tema:
[Información para subir una aplicación](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk)

Como alternativa podría sugerirte que solicites al desarrollador de tu biblioteca que la actualice para que puedas dejar de tener este inconveniente o buscar una alternativa a la misma.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos.